# Does a high CPU usage -say 98%- necessary mean the database will be slower?

Tags: python, postgresql

I have 4 python scripts each running in their own virtual machine. The scripts are accessing a central postgresql database. All scripts are reading from the same table but posting to different tables in the same database. The database is located on its own machine. The DB machine has 8 CPUs.

Running the command `top` on the database server shows:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
12609 postgres  20   0 3700m 563m 559m R  98.4  3.5   1602:57 postgres
12603 postgres  20   0 3700m 927m 923m R  97.8  5.8   1603:17 postgres
20619 postgres  20   0 3700m 455m 451m R  96.4  2.8 237:36.05 postgres
12616 postgres  20   0 3700m 1.0g 1.0g R  94.8  6.4   1547:26 postgres
```

The CPU usage is extremely high. I have noted that my scripts have become slower all of a sudden hence my interrogation of resources using top. Question is, am i better off letting each script run alone i.e. with db exclusivity or the high CPU usage seen does not necessary slow down the database and I should be looking elsewhere to optimize my speeds?

**Tuned Postgresq**

I have tried tunning postgres as directed [here](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server) but I don't see any increase in speeds or even higher memory utilization by postgres. I have set the shared buffers to 3.5GB as my machine has 16GB and edited the shared memory kannel to 4GB

```
$sysctl -p
kernel.shmmax = 4294967296
kernel.shmall = 1073741824
vm.overcommit_memory = 1
```

Comment: This _could_ be a sign of bad database design: do you have proper PK/FK constraints and indexes, and are your typical queries able to use these? Try to obtain a few typical queries and the corresponding query plans. (and maybe add them to your question) BTW: the RSS is extremely high; did set work_mem extremely high?

Comment: You really need to figure out what that CPU time is being used *for*. Use the `auto_explain` and `pg_stat_statements` / `pg_stat_plans` modules, use `explain analyze`, do query logging, etc. Profile with `perf top -az` if you're comfortable reading stacks.

Comment: BTW: it could also mean that the entire _working set_ of your queries is located in the shared buffers, and the queries's work consists only of scanning and combining these pieces of memory.

Comment: @CraigRinger I wish I new where to start running those queries... but I'll Google and revert. Got pointers in the mean time?

Comment: @wildplasser what do you mean by `the RSS is extremely high?

Comment: RSS := "Resident Set Size" , it is named "RES" in your "top" listing. (and in your case it is caused by the shared_buffers mapped into each processes' memory map)

Comment: I suppose you have those 8 cores there to do something :)  In itself, this is not a bad sign.  You have to compare it with similar data from low-load times (if any).  Also, you can have a look at any time what your processes are doing with [pg_view](https://github.com/zalando/pg_view) (disclaimer: I work for Zalando).

Comment: If there are wait times and queues - then it's bad for the database server.